# Find and Replace Files in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm updating a file in every user profile. The location is fairly deep \profiles\\appdata\roaming\microsoft\imagelogo.jpg and I'm replacing it with a newer file of the same name. I would like to do this for all profiles. Is there a good way to replace all files based on filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of doing this in one swoop would be as follows:

```
cd path\to\user\profiles
for /d %i in (*) do copy /y newimagelogo.jpg %1\appdata\roaming\microsoft
```

Despite this, I'd use with Judaslscariot's answer for the following reason:

If a user is logged on when you run this, the image currently in that user's roaming profile will overwrite the image you've just copied, when they log off.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to avoid using a login script. Your method worked. The profile sync will work as intended so long as the modified date is newer.

Answer (score 3):

Create a simple batch script (.bat) to copy the file from a central share to the current users profile:

```
dir \\centralfileserver\path\imagelogo.jpg
if errorlevel = 1 goto exit
xcopy \\centralfileserver\path\imagelogo.jpg %USERPROFILE%\appdata\roaming\microsoft\imagelogo.jpg
:exit
```

Assign it as a [logon script](http://www.petri.co.il/setting-up-logon-script-through-gpo-windows-server-2008.htm) for all users via Group Policy

Comment: Copying files with the logonscript tends to increase the logontime. Also no errorhandling! Example: What happens when "centralfileserver" is not available?

Comment: Nothing. Use ERRORLEVEL if you want error handling

Comment: Added a little error handling for the pleasure of @Tom ;)

Comment: `if exist \\centralfileserver\path\imagelogo.jpg xcopy...` should also work.